# How to add fix vertical axis to focus + context zooming timeseries

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a visualisation based on [this interactive time-series](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) composed of two plots. I would like to add a set of vertical lines in both plots indicating specific dates like

```
var labels = [
    ["Christmas 2011", 2011-12-25],
    ["Christmas 2012", 2012-12-25],
];
```

with a vertical axis, which doesn't move in the plot on the bottom and move accordingly with the zoom level in the top plot.

Should I `focus.append.line`? But then I should I provide the exact coordinates?

Comment: All you should need to do is to append the lines to `focus` and `context`, using the respective scales to determine the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

To add a line to your particular point:

```
var xval = x2(new Date('2008-12-25'));

focus.append("line")
     .attr({
            x1:xval,
            x2:xval,
            y1:0,
            y2:height,
            stroke:'black',
            'stroke-width':1
          });
```

This is using `x2` and `height` from the code you linked to above.

To add a label:

```
focus.append("text")
     .attr({
            x:xval,
            y:height/2,
            'font-size':'1em',
            fill:'red'
          })
     .text('Christmas 2008');
```

This doesn't work when you zoom in to a particular date range. I haven't figured out how to do that. I guess there must be a refresh event that I need to hook into or something.